# How to share a library on Arduino Playground?

Tags: library

I have written an ISR-based timer library for Arduino Uno and I would like to share it on the website and get it reviewed.

But I am stuck on how to post it to playground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Arduino Playground library list](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LibraryList) is a wiki page (like everything on the playground). That means anyone can log in to edit it and add links to their own libraries. The "Log In" and "Sign Up" links are at the top right of the Arduino site. When you first go to edit a Playground page you'll be taken to a "Password required" page but don't worry, this is only to prevent spam and the password is pre-filled. You only need to click the "I'm not a robot" checkbox, wait for the green checkmark to appear, then click "Submit".

There are a couple of important things to note though. Firstly, the Playground library list isn't there for getting your work reviewed. It's a place to post things that are functional and ready to be used by other people. If you need someone to help with your project then you can maybe post on the Arduino forums. Alternatively, if you have specific questions, you can post here on Arduino SE.

If you're ready to post your library online, you also have to be aware that the Playground itself won't host your code. You can put a link there and maybe some documentation. However, you'll need to host your code somewhere else, such as [Github](https://github.com).